# How to install all Android SDK licenses using command line tool?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, sdk, flutter-dependencies

[I am getting the error as below even though I granted access to all installations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJMdB.png)

Comment: failed SDK installation!. reinstall the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run from terminal: `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. You need to accept Android SDK licenses.